# The torus as a projective plane curve $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$

Tags: complex-geometry

The homogeneous polynomial $F(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3$ clearly defines a smooth projective curve $X\subset\mathbb{P}^2$.

It is easy to see that $\pi:X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ defined by
$$\pi([x:y:z])=[x:y] \ , $$
is a well defined holomorphic map of degree $3$. Now if we let $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$ be the three cube root of $-1$, one can show that the only ramification points of $\pi$ are $[\epsilon_1:1:0],[\epsilon_2:1:0],[\epsilon_3:1:0]$, and they are all triple points, hence by Riemann-Hurwitz's formula we find that
$$g(X)=1 \ , $$
therefore $X$ is isomorphic to a torus $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$.

My question is: how does this isomorphism "work"? I just can't see it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The covering map $f\colon \mathbb{C} \to X$ is defined by
$$
f(z) \;=\; \bigl[-\mathrm{cm}(z) : -\mathrm{sm}(z) : 1\bigr]
$$
where $\mathrm{cm}(z)$ and $\mathrm{sm}(z)$ are the Dixonian elliptic functions (which are known to satisfy $\mathrm{cm}(z)^3 +\mathrm{sm}(z)^3 = 1$).  See [this answer by J. M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36506/1726) for an overview of the Dixonian elliptic functions, including pictures of them on the complex plane.

The lattice $\Lambda$ in this case is $\pi_3\mathbb{Z} + \pi_3e^{2\pi i/3}\mathbb{Z}$, which is a regular lattice of equilateral triangles on the complex plane. Here $\pi_3 \approx 5.29992$ is the value of $B(1/3,1/3)$, 
where $B$ is the [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). (One could of course eliminate the $\pi_3$'s by using the function $f(\pi_3 z)$ instead.)

Note that $\mathrm{cm}(z)$ and $\mathrm{sm}(z)$ have poles, and that the function $f$ can be extended holomorphically to these poles so as to make the covering map onto.  In particular,
$$
f\bigl(-\pi_3/3\bigr) \;=\;  [1:-1:0]\qquad\text{and}\qquad f\bigl(e^{\pm i\pi/3}\pi_3/3\bigr) \;=\; \bigl[1:e^{\pm i\pi/3}:0\bigr].
$$

Comment: Can you kindly look at this [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/259212/on-xkyk-1-and-the-dixonian-elliptic-functions)?