# Tilings and meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, tiling, meromorphic-functions

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35671/doubly-periodic-functions-as-tessellations-other-than-parallelograms) and its answer by "J.M." were quite informative and inspire other questions.

If a function is meromorphic on $\mathbb C$ and doubly periodic then, as we all learned at our mother's knee, there is a fundamental domain that is a parallelogram.  So someone asked whether one could do the same with the standard tiling of the plane by regular hexagons, so that the restriction of the function to one hexagon is just a shift of its restriction to any of the other hexagons.  "J.M." 's answer was that that is exactly what happens with ["Dixon's elliptic functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_elliptic_functions).  This in no way conflicts with the existence of a fundamental domain that is a parallelogram --- indeed a rectangle (that's an exercise whose solution may take you five seconds).

All this immediately inspires two other questions:

- What about other periodic tilings?  For example, there is a periodic tiling by hexagons, squares, and triangles.  Might the restriction of some doubly periodic meromorphic function to any of those be a shift or maybe a shift followed by a rotation, of the restriction to any of the others?  For *that* tiling, rotation as well as translation becomes relevant.
- <s>What about aperiodic tilings?  We'd want a function meromorpic on the whole plane whose restriction to any tile is a shift-plus-rotation of its restriction to any of the infinitely many tiles of the same shape.  For which tilings does such a thing exist?</s> 
  [Aperiodic tilings won't work here. That follows immediately from some basic stuff from complex variables.]

[image: An aperiodic tiling by rhombi of two shapes]

Comment: Unfortunately, my complex geometry isn't sufficient to comment on the meromorphic properties, but I'm reminded of a notion called '[pattern-equivariance](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~kellendonk/Arbeiten/jpa2003.pdf)' of functions on tilings of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into coefficient groups (originally the reals, but later generalised to the integers and other locally compact groups). These functions turn out the be the correct setting to form a 'locally defined' cohomology theory for tilings, as opposed to the previously global approaches via Cech cohomology of their hulls/tiling space.

Comment: @DanRust : What are "coefficient groups"?  Maybe a typo for "quotient groups"? $\qquad$

Comment: Sorry, it's a cohomology term, as in the universal coefficients theorem. As I said, it seems only loosely related to your question, but seems like something you may be interested in nonetheless.