# Relationship between Dixonian elliptic functions and Borwein cubic theta functions

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory, theta-functions

In [this paper](http://www.math.illinois.edu/REGS/reports10/Schultz.pdf), it says that the three Borwein cubic theta functions obey the identity $a(q)^{3}=b(q)^{3}+c(q)^{3}$, which is strongly reminiscent of the identity that Dixonian elliptic functions obey $\mathrm{sm}^{3}(z)+\mathrm{cm}^{3}(z)=1$. What relationship (if any) exists between the [Dixonian elliptic functions](http://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/wpapers/s54conflaj.html) and the Borwein cubic theta functions?

Comment: Hmm, you may be on to something. ${}_2 F_1\left({{\frac13}\atop{}}{{}\atop{\frac43}}{{\frac23}\atop{}}\mid z\right)$ crops up in Dixonian theory, while ${}_2 F_1\left({{\frac13}\atop{}}{{}\atop{1}}{{\frac23}\atop{}}\mid z\right)$ crops up in relating the Borwein theta functions... it might take some tedious algebra to entirely display the connection, though.

Comment: This is a good observation. My student Ng Say Tiong and I have looked at it a few years ago and come up with some results. These are contained in Say Tiong's Master thesis at National University of Singapore.

Comment: Related post. [$f^3+g^3=1$ for two meromorphic functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29935/f3-g3-1-for-two-meromorphic-functions)

Answer (score 2):

(*Too long for a comment*.)

And to add to the mystery, there's also a $x^3+y^3=1$ relation  involving Ramanujan's beautiful ***cubic continued fraction***,
$$C(q)=\frac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta^3(6\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)\,\eta^3(3\tau)}=\cfrac{q^{1/3}}{1+\cfrac{q+q^2}{1+\cfrac{q^2+q^4}{1+\cfrac{q^3+q^6}{1+\ddots}}}}$$

where $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$ and Dedekind eta function $\eta(\tau)$. Define,
$$\alpha =\left(\left(\frac{4C^3(q)+1}{C(q)}\right)^3-27\right)^{1/4}$$
$$\beta=\left(\left(\frac{4C^3(q^3)+1}{C(q^3)}\right)^3-27\right)^{1/4}$$
then we have the relation,

> $$\alpha^3+\left(\frac{3\eta(3\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^3 =\left(\alpha+\frac{3^2}{\beta}\right)^3\tag1$$

Equivalently, and more simply in terms of eta quotients,

> $$\left(\frac{\eta^3(\tau)}{\eta^3(3\tau)}\right)^3+\left(\frac{3\eta(3\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^3 =\left(\frac{\eta^3(\tau)+9\eta^3(9\tau)}{\eta^3(3\tau)}\right)^3\tag2$$
> See also this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259013/can-we-use-the-rogers-ramanujan-cfrac-to-parameterize-the-fermat-quintic-x5y).

$\color{blue}{Update:}$
I just realized that if we multiply $(2)$ by $\eta^6(3\tau)$ to get,
$$\left(\frac{\eta^3(\tau)}{\eta(3\tau)}\right)^3+\left(\frac{3\eta^3(3\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^3 =\left(\frac{\eta^3(\tau)+9\eta^3(9\tau)}{\eta(3\tau)}\right)^3$$
*this is in fact the Borwein's*,
$$b^3(q)+c^3(q) = a^3(q)$$
where,
$$a(q) = 1+6\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{q^{3n+1}}{1-q^{3n+1}}-\frac{q^{3n+2}}{1-q^{3n+2}}\right)$$
and similarly for $b(q),\,c(q)$.

Answer (score 1):

In a Master's thesis [1], the author makes the insightful observation in Section 5.2 that if $smu$ and $cmu$ are the standard Dixonian elliptic functions, where
$$ cm^3u+sm^3u-3{\alpha}*cmu*smu=1$$ with $\alpha\neq-1$, and if the following are defined as

\begin{align}
& z=\vartheta_1(\pi/3)*u/\vartheta_1'(0) \\
& s(u)=\vartheta_1(z)/\vartheta_1(z+\pi/3) \\
& c(u)=-\vartheta_1(z-\pi/3)/\vartheta_1(z+\pi/3) \\
& \alpha=-a(q)*b(q)
\end{align}
then the functions $s(u)$ and $c(u)$ have the same Taylor expansions as $smu$ and $cmu$ at 0, where $a(q)$ and $b(q)$ are the BBG cubic theta functions (as above).
 The author states this as a conjecture. But since the Taylor expansion is unique within it's radius of convergence, he has essentially outlined a proof of the result without providing the specific details. This is entirely based on the author's Theorem 5.1.1 which states a formula that is equivalent to a Jacobian theta function identity proved by Liu.
The paper is worth reading even though it contains some errors. For example on the final page the author fails to observe that $\vartheta_1(z,q)$ is an odd function of $z$.
I can't assert the full accuracy of the claims made in the paper as I have only made a cursory reading of it. 

References:
[1]
[Elliptic Functions, Theta Functions and Identities, Ng Say Tiong](http://scholarbank.nus.edu.sg/bitstream/handle/1063/1/elliptic%20functions,%20theta%20functions%20and%20identities.pdf?sequence=1)