# On $x^3+y^3=z^3$, the Dixonian elliptic functions, and the Borwein cubic theta functions

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory, hypergeometric-function, theta-functions

The *Borwein cubic theta functions* $a(q),b(q),c(q)$ and the **doubly**-periodic *Dixonian elliptic functions* $\mathrm{sm}(z), \mathrm{cm}(z)$ parameterize the *Fermat cubic* $x^3+y^3=1$, so

$$\frac{b^3(q)}{a^3(q)}+\frac{c^3(q)}{a^3(q)} =1\tag1$$

$$\mathrm{sm}^{3}(z)+\mathrm{cm}^{3}(z)=1\tag2$$

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36772/) asks if there is any relation between the Borwein and Dixonian versions. It is known that the former is associated with $_2F_1\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;\color{blue}1;u\big)$ while the latter is with $_2F_1\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;\color{blue}{\tfrac43};v\big)$.

For argument $q=e^{2\pi i \sqrt{-n}}$, we have the nice [relationship](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259013/can-we-use-the-rogers-ramanujan-cfrac-to-parameterize-the-fermat-quintic-x5y),

$$\large \frac{_2F_1\Big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;1;\tfrac{b^3(q)}{a^3(q)} \Big)}{_2F_1\Big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;1;\tfrac{c^3(q)}{a^3(q)} \Big)}=\sqrt{3n}$$

> **Q:** By analogy, does the ratio,
>   $$\frac{_2F_1\Big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;\tfrac43;\mathrm{sm}^3(z) \Big)}{_2F_1\Big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;\tfrac43;\mathrm{cm}^3(z) \Big)}=\,??\tag3$$
>   evaluate to anything "meaningful" for appropriate choice of argument $z$?

---

**P.S.** To test this conjecture, for the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, we have the *Dedekind eta* quotients $\alpha(q), \beta(q)$ parameterization (given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259013/can-we-use-the-rogers-ramanujan-cfrac-to-parameterize-the-fermat-quintic-x5y)) and the **singly**-periodic trigonometric functions,

$$\alpha^8(q)+\beta^8(q)=1\tag4$$
$$\sin^2 z+\cos^2 z=1\tag5$$

The analogous ratios,
$$\frac{_2F_1\Big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1; \beta^8(q) \Big)}{ _2F_1\Big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1; \alpha^8(q)\Big)}=\sqrt{4n}$$
and choice of $0<z<1$,

$$\frac{_2F_1\Big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;\tfrac32; \cos^2 z \Big)}{ _2F_1\Big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;\tfrac32; \sin^2 z \Big)}=\Big(\frac{\pi}{2z}-1\Big) \tan z$$
so $(3)$ *might* indeed evaluate to some closed-form, perhaps involving the fundamental constant of Dixonian functions $\large \pi_3=\frac{\sqrt3}{2\pi}\Gamma^3\big(\tfrac13\big)$.

Comment: As soon as I saw the title of this question, I thought that you were probably the author. I admire the work you do here.

Comment: @martycohen: Thanks, Marty. :)

Comment: After a good night's rest, I figured out the answer. See this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/259212/on-xkyk-1-the-borwein-cubic-theta-functions-and-the-dixonian-elliptic-fun) for a possible generalization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that

$$\int_0^z\frac{\mathrm du}{\left(1-u^3\right)^{2/3}}=\operatorname{sm}^{(-1)}(z)=z\;{}_2 F_1\left({{\frac13,\frac23}\atop{\frac43}}\middle|z^3\right)$$

and

$$\int_z^1\frac{\mathrm du}{\left(1-u^3\right)^{2/3}}=\operatorname{cm}^{(-1)}(z)$$

along with

$$\frac{\pi_3}{3}=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm du}{\left(1-u^3\right)^{2/3}}=\frac13 B\left(\frac13,\frac13\right)$$

so within a *limited domain*, your expression ought to simplify to

$$\frac{{}_2 F_1\left({{\frac13,\frac23}\atop{\frac43}}\middle|\operatorname{sm}^3(z)\right)}{{}_2 F_1\left({{\frac13,\frac23}\atop{\frac43}}\middle|\operatorname{cm}^3(z)\right)}=\frac{\frac{z}{\operatorname{sm}(z)}}{\frac{\frac{\pi_3}{3}-z}{\operatorname{cm}(z)}}=\frac{z}{\frac{\pi_3}{3}-z}\frac{\operatorname{cm}(z)}{\operatorname{sm}(z)}$$

Note the phrase "limited domain". This is expected, in the same way that $\arcsin\sin z=z$ and $\arccos\cos z=z$ are also only valid within a limited domain. In particular, the relation only works within the intersection of the domains of validity of $\operatorname{sm}^{(-1)}(\operatorname{sm}(z))$ and $\operatorname{cm}^{(-1)}(\operatorname{cm}(z))$ (both of which are, perhaps not surprisingly, hexagons), which is the rhombus with corners at $0,\frac{\pi_3}{3}\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{3}\right),\frac{\pi_3}{3},\frac{\pi_3}{3}\exp\left(-\frac{\pi i}{3}\right)$.

Comment: @JM: Yes, I believe it is $0<z<1$. This morning I posted such relations [in MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/259212/on-xkyk-1-and-the-dixonian-elliptic-functions) for $\sin, \mathrm{sn}, \mathrm{sm}$ and asked if it could be generalized from $a=1/2$ and $a=2/3$, to $a=1/4$ and $a=1/6$.

Comment: @JM: Perhaps you can answer that [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/259212/on-xkyk-1-and-the-dixonian-elliptic-functions) as well for $a=1/4$?  :)

Comment: The cases $a=1/4,1/6$ have been posted here http://mathoverflow.net/a/259267/82588

Comment: @Tito, $0<z<1$ is but a small cut of the rhombus I mentioned in my answer. :)

Comment: @J.M.: And someone also [did work](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/259013/can-we-use-the-rogers-ramanujan-cfrac-to-parameterize-the-fermat-quintic-x5y) on $x^5+y^5=1$.