# Pi, the Lemniscatic elliptic functions, and the Dixonian elliptic functions

Tags: geometry, pi, elliptic-functions, beta-function

> $n=2$

**Circle:** $x^2+y^2=c^2$. We all know the role of $\pi$ in the circle and the trigonometric functions,

$$\pi_2 = \color{brown}{B\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12\big)}=3.1415\dots$$

with the *[beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)* $B(x,y)$ and circumference for $D=1$

$$C=\pi_2 = 3.1415\dots$$

> $n=4$

**Lemniscate:** $(x^2+y^2)^2=2c^2(x^2-y^2)$ (or $r^2=2c^2\cos2\theta$ in polar form):

$\hskip1.4in$[image]

The [lemniscate constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemniscateConstant.html) $L$ plays an [analogous role](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html) to $\pi$,

$$L =\frac{\color{brown}{B\big(\tfrac14,\tfrac14\big)}}{2\sqrt2}= \frac{B\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac14\big)}{2}=  \frac{\sqrt\pi\,\Gamma\big(\tfrac14\big)}{2\Gamma\big(\tfrac34\big)}=\frac{\Gamma^2\big(\tfrac14\big)}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}=2.622057\dots$$

and if $c=1$,

$$\text{Arclength} = 2L = 5.2441\dots$$

The minimal half period $\omega_1$ of the [*lemniscatic elliptic functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscatic_elliptic_function) is,

$$\omega_1=\frac{L}{\sqrt2}=\frac{\Gamma^2\big(\tfrac14\big)}{4\sqrt{\pi}}$$

> $n=3$

**Object?:** ($3$rd or $6$th deg poly?)  However, it seems we missed a step,

$$\pi_3 = \color{brown}{B\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac13\big)}=2^{1/3}\,B\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac13\big) =\frac{\Gamma^2\big(\tfrac13\big)}{\Gamma\big(\tfrac23\big)}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\Gamma^3\big(\tfrac13\big)}{2\pi}=5.29991\dots$$

which conveniently is the fundamental constant of the [*Dixonian elliptic functions*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090523/on-x3y3-z3-the-dixonian-elliptic-functions-and-the-borwein-cubic-theta-f).

> **Q:** So does the constant $\pi_3$ play an analogous role for some geometric object akin to the circle and lemniscate?

**Edit:** To clarify (courtesy of reuns' comments): to know the arc length of a circle you need $\pi_2$. For a lemniscate, you need  $L$. So is there a simple geometric object where to know its arc length you need  $\pi_3$?

Comment: @reuns: That's partly what I'm asking. A ***third*** closed curve like the circle and lemniscate to pair with $\pi_3$. Assuming there is one.

Comment: @J.M. Paging J.M.

Comment: Why don't you say what are the corresponding algebraic curves, functions fields, parametrization and and how $B(1/n,1/n)$ is related to them ?

Comment: @reuns: Let me put it another way. To know the arc length of a circle you need $\pi=\pi_2$. To know the arc length of a lemniscate, you need $\pi_4$. The question then, is there a simple geometric object where to know its arc length you need $\pi_3$?

Comment: And, of course, what about $\pi_n$?

Comment: @martycohen: You mean $\pi_n = B(1/n,1/n)$? The notation, I believe, is by Dixon.

Comment: @reuns: Feel free to answer when you remember. The relationship between $B(1/2,1/n)$ and $B(1/n,1/n)$ just involves algebraic numbers so is not really crucial. What is important is the name of that third geometric object.

Comment: Does the curve really have to be closed? My intuition tells me the odd order makes a closed curve unlikely.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: I'll be happy with any curve that has some literature behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Langer and Singer, in [their paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00032-013-0211-5), present the *trefoil*, which has the Cartesian equation

$$(x^2+y^2)^3=2(x^3-3xy^2)$$

and polar equation $r^3=2\cos3\theta$:

$\hskip1.3in$[image: trefoil]

Using the normal formula for determining the arclength of a polar curve, its total arclength comes out to

$$\text{Arclength} =\sqrt{3}\,\pi_3=9.179724\dots$$

Additionally, they also present a unit-speed parametrization in terms of the Dixon functions. Letting $\sigma=\operatorname{sm}\dfrac{s}{\sqrt3}$ and $\chi=\operatorname{cm}\dfrac{s}{\sqrt3}$, we have the arclength parametrization

$$f(s)=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{3\chi\sigma^4}{2(\chi^3\sigma^3-1)}\\\dfrac{\sqrt{3}\chi\sigma(1+\chi^3)}{2(1-\chi^3\sigma^3)}\end{pmatrix}$$

See [this related paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-1037-0) as well.

Comment: Great! So the Cartesian equation is indeed a $6$-deg poly. And we have a family of arclengths as $$B\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12\big) \approx 3.1415$$  $$\frac1{\sqrt2}B\big(\tfrac14,\tfrac14\big) \approx 5.2441$$  $$\sqrt3\,B\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac13\big) \approx 9.1797$$

Comment: I actually did a cursory search after commenting on your question yesterday, and I was surprised that that paper quickly showed up in my results. :)

Comment: Do you suppose there is one for $B\big(\tfrac16,\tfrac16\big)$ as well?

Comment: I haven't had the time to make a detailed investigation, but it seems the bibliographies of the two papers I linked to suggest that [rose curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rose.html) or [sinusoidal spirals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SinusoidalSpiral.html) ought to have a total arclength expressible as a beta function in exceptional cases. However, a comparably simple arclength parametrization for those seems very unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

To make my comments clear:

- Look at the differential equation $g'(x)^2 = 1-g(x)^n$. The solution depends only on the initial conditions $(g(0),g'(0))$. The initial condition $g(0) = 0$ implies $g'(0) \pm 1$ and two possible real solutions. If for some  $x_0 \ne 0$, then $g$ is periodic with period $x_0$ or $2 x_0$.
- Let $$F_n(z) = \int_0^z \frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^n}}, \quad G_n = F_n^{-1}, \quad G_n'(z) = \frac{1}{F_n'(G_n(z))}, \quad G_n'(z)^2 = 1- G_n(z)^n$$
  $G_n(x)$ is real for $x$ real and $G_n(0)=0$; thus, it satisfies the preceding differential equation.
- Let $$\omega_n = \int_{\gamma} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^n}}$$ where the contour $\gamma$ goes from $s=0$, encloses the branch point $s=1$ in a clockwise direction and goes back to $s=0$, with the branch of $\sqrt{1-s^n}$ chosen such that it stays analytic on this path. Then with a change of variable $s = G_n(u)$, we obtain
  $$\omega_n= \int_{0}^{x_0} \frac{G_n'(u)}{\sqrt{1-G_n(u)^n}}du = x_0$$
  Where $G_n(x_0) = G_n(0) = 0$ and hence $G_n$ is $2 x_0$-periodic. But choosing the branch of $\sqrt{1-s^n}$ correctly, we have the other expression
  $$2\omega_n = 2\int_0^1+\int_1^0 \frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^n}} = 4 \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^n}}=4 \int_0^1 \frac{v^{1/n-1}dv}{n\sqrt{1-v}}= \frac{4}{n} B(1/2,1/n)$$
- $z \mapsto (G_n(z),G_n'(z))$ parameterizes the curve $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2, y^2 = 1-x^n\}$ and the period $2\omega_n$ is the arc-length (?) of $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, y^2 = 1-x^n\}$ in those coordinates.