# Question about Picard's Little Theorem proof

Tags: complex-analysis, covering-spaces

I'm trying to study the Picard's Little Theorem, from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63401) I noticed an interesting (also seems very simple) way of showing theorem, which is introduced by @Matt E also from [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Picard%27s_Theorem) a likely proof. But there is some points which are not so clear to me.

Please allow me to cite the proof from [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Picard%27s_Theorem):

> For this proof, we use the fact that there is a *holomorphic covering map*
> :$\phi: \Bbb D \to \Bbb C \backslash \{0, 1\}$ 
> where $\Bbb D = \{z \in \Bbb C:  |z| < 1\}$.
> This follows from the Riemann Uniformization Theorem, but is much easier to prove.
> Indeed, such a covering is given by the elliptic modular function.
> Now suppose that an entire function $f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ omits two different complex values.
> Assume for simplicity that the omitted values are $0$ and $1$.
> This can always be achieved by postcomposing $f$ with a suitable complex affine map.
> Because $\Bbb C$ is simply connected and $\phi$ is a covering, we can lift $f$ to a holomorphic function:
> :$F: \Bbb C \to \Bbb D$
> with $\phi \circ F = f$.
> By Liouville's Theorem, $F$ is constant.
> Therefore $f$ is also constant.

I tried to search it everywhere but it only makes things more complecated.

My first question is both of them (@Matt E and ProofWiki)mentioned the holomorphic covering map is given by a **modular function**(Without considering the Uniformization theorem, I think this might make the proof much harder), but what is this function and how it maps $\Bbb C \backslash \{0,1\}$ to unit circle? Then, at the end they mentioned "we can lift $f$ to a holomorphic function", I believe this follows Lifting lemma, but I can't find the suitable one, how can we prove this is true for holomorphic case?

Thank you very much fro your help.

Comment: For the Elliptic Modular Function $J(z)$ See e.g.  https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371655 .