# Proving two entire functions are constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be entire functions such that $f^n+g^n=1$, where $n\geq 3$ is an integer. Prove that $f$ and $g$ are constant.

I suppose I should somehow prove that either $f$ or $g$ is bounded so that I can apply Liouville's Theorem, but I don't see how. I tried setting the derivative of the left hand side equal to zero and work with that but that did not seem to work.

Comment: Is the equation supposed to hold for all $n\ge 3$?

Comment: @MarkBennet For a single specific $n$ satisfying $n\ge 3$.

Comment: No, just for one $n\ge3$ (and note that $n=2$ wonÄt work becasue of $\sin, \cos$)

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29935/f3-g3-1-for-two-meromorphic-functions) for the case $n>3$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a proof adapted from Remmert's book *Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory*, page 236.

Suppose $g\neq 0$. Since $f$ and $g$ cannot have common zeros, $f/g$ is a meromorphic function that takes the value $w$ at $z$ if and only if $f(z)=wg(z)$.

We can factor the given equation as

$$1=\prod_1^n (f-\zeta_ig),$$

where the $\zeta_i$ are roots of $x^n+1$. Dividing through by $g$, we see $f/g$ cannot take the (distinct) values $\zeta_i$. By Picard's theorem for meromorphic functions, a meromorphic function that omits $3$ values is constant. So $f/g$ is constant, $f=cg$ for a constant $c$, and the rest follows easily.

Comment: +1, but I don't see that the assumption that $g$ never vanishes is required.

Comment: @JonathanY. That notation means that $g$ is not the constant $0$ function.

Comment: At least, that's what I intended it to mean...

Comment: Potato, well then, that makes perfect sense ;)

Comment: @Potato Did you mean to say "Dividing through by $g^n$"?

Comment: @user87317 Yes, sorry.