# Pythagorean Identities other than Trigonometric

Tags: functions, pythagorean-triples

Are there any identities which follow the Pythagorean pattern,
$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
besides the standard trigonometric and hyperbolic trigonometric Pythagorean identities (e.g. $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$) and those derived from them? 
Preferably, these functions shouldn't be reducible to the trig identities, but those are acceptable as generalizations.

Alternatively, what other non-trivial functions parameterize the *circle* $x^2+y^2=1$? (Just like there are also functions that parameterize the *Fermat cubic* [$x^3+y^3=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29935/f3-g3-1-for-two-meromorphic-functions)?)

Comment: What do you mean by a pythagorean pattern?

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what are you asking

Comment: The Cosine Law for triangles: $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc \cos A$ is an immediate consequence of Pythagoras.  Your Q is a bit vague.

Comment: Yes, this was a little too vague. I'll edit it to make it more clear what I do and don't want.

Comment: Can we guys re-open this question? It seems clear enough now.

Comment: @Goldname I guess he/she wants identities in the form $$\text{something}^{n}+\text{something different}^{n}=\text{another thing}^{\text{which can have}\\ \text{or not have} \\ \text{exponents here}}.$$.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle: And all with the same even exponent $n$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Yes. My *"equation"* encompasses that. But I guess he/she wouldn't get hurt if it lacks an exponent after the equality.

Comment: @LoganClark: You can vote to re-open your own question.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII How do I do that?

Comment: @LoganClark: Click on the re-open button that is below your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Jacobi theta functions*,
$$\vartheta_2(q)^4+\vartheta_4(q)^4 = \vartheta_3(q)^4\tag1 $$
the *[Weber modular functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_modular_function)*,
$$\mathfrak{f}_1(\tau)^8+\mathfrak{f}_2(\tau)^8 = \mathfrak{f}(\tau)^8\tag2$$
the *[elliptic modulus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticModulus.html)*,
$$k^2+k'\,^2=1\tag3$$
and the *Dedekind eta function*,
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt2\,\eta(\tfrac{\tau}2)\,\eta^2(2\tau)}{\eta^3(\tau)}\right)^8+\left(\frac{\eta^2(\tfrac{\tau}2)\,\eta(2\tau)}{\eta^3(\tau)}\right)^8 = 1\tag4$$
which, with the nome $q=e^{\pi i \tau}$, has a beautiful continued fraction studied by Ramanujan, 
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\eta(\tfrac{\tau}{2})\,\eta^2(2\tau)}{\eta^3(\tau)} = \cfrac{\sqrt{2}\,q^{1/8}}{1+\cfrac{q}{1+q+\cfrac{q^2}{1+q^2+\cfrac{q^3}{1+q^3+\ddots}}}}$$
These four can be derived from each other.

---

**P.S.** You might also be interested in the Borwein's version,
$$b(q)^3+c(q)^3=a(q)^3$$
with cubic theta functions. There's even a [$26$th deg analogue](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107327/a-14th-and-26th-power-dedekind-eta-function-identity),
$$x_1^{26}+x_2^{26}+\dots = 1$$
using the Dedekind eta function again, but you'd need more than two addends.

Answer (score 2):

The Jacobi elliptic functions $\mathrm{sn}(z;k)$, $\mathrm{cn}(z;k)$ and $\mathrm{dn}(z;k)$ of an additional parameter $k$, which are defined by the differential equations $$\mathrm{sn}'(z;k) = \mathrm{cn}(z;k) \cdot \mathrm{dn}(z;k) \; \; \mathrm{and} \; \mathrm{sn}(0;k) = 0,$$ $$\mathrm{cn}'(z;k) = -\mathrm{sn}(z;k) \cdot \mathrm{dn}(z;k), \; \; \mathrm{cn}(0;k) = 1,$$ and $$\mathrm{dn}'(z;k) = -k^2 \mathrm{sn}(z;k) \cdot \mathrm{cn}(z;k), \; \; \mathrm{dn}(0;k) = 1$$ satisfy the "Pythagorean" formulas $$\mathrm{sn}(z;k)^2 + \mathrm{cn}(z;k)^2 = 1$$ and $$k^2 \mathrm{sn}(z;k)^2 + \mathrm{dn}(z;k)^2 = 1.$$ As $k$ approaches $0$, $\mathrm{sn}(z;k)$ approaches $\mathrm{sin}(z)$, $\mathrm{cn}(z;k)$ approaches $\mathrm{cos}(z)$, and $\mathrm{dn}(z;k)$ approaches $1$.

Comment: On the other hand, since $\operatorname{sn}(u\mid m)=\sin(\operatorname{am}(u\mid m))$ and $\operatorname{cn}(u\mid m)=\cos(\operatorname{am}(u\mid m))$, where $\operatorname{am}(u\mid m)$ is the Jacobian amplitude, this in a way violates the OP's stipulation of "these functions shouldn't be reducible to the trig identities".

Answer (score 1):

The [hyperbolic trig functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function):

$$\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$$

$$\operatorname{sech}^2(x)+\tanh^2(x)=1$$

$$\coth ^{2}x-\operatorname {csch}^2x=1$$

Notice the signs are a little wacky...

Answer (score 0):

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2.$$ A geometric interpretation of this: In the Cartesian plane, with $X=(a,b), Y=(c,d), O=(0,0),$  we have $$a^2+b^2=XO^2\; \text { and }\; c^2+d^2=YO^2$$  $$ \text {while }\; |ac+bd|=XO\cdot YO\cdot |\cos XOY|$$ $$\text {and }\; |ad-bc|=XO\cdot YO\cdot |\sin XOY|.$$