# General method for finding parametric equations for polynomials _in rational functions_

Tags: algebraic-geometry, parametrization

Is there a general method for trying to finding parametric equations for polynomial equations?

The classic example of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ having multiple parameterizations:

\begin{array}{rcl}
(x,y) &=& (\sin t, \cos t) \\
(x,y) &=& (\cos t, \sin t) \\
(x,y) &=& \left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)
\end{array}

which are easily seen to work by plugging in. Note that the first two involve elementary functions, but the last one only rational functions.

I'm curious about higher degree polynomials. Is there a general method to find a parameterized set of equations in rational functions? That is, **is there an algorithm for extracting the parameter functions for $x$ and $y$ from the equation (or arbitrary sets of equations over $v\ge1$)? And if not, is there a characterization of which implicit sets can be parametrized?**

Take the (random off the top of my head) example:

$$x y^3 + x^2 y + x y = 1$$

Is there a set $x(t), y(t)$ for this that can be found algorithmically? (I may well be naive here, not realizing something obvious, or maybe the entire field of algebraic geometry is geared towards possible solutions to this).

One can do the reverse process of creating an implicit set of equations via Gröbner basis calculation, trying to eliminate $t$. Or likewise in the forward direction if you can eliminate variables one-by-one with GB that would suffice to parameterize via one of the original variables. But in general if elimination isn't possible, is there still an algorithm to (even partially) parameterize?

Comment: A curve over an algebraically closed field can be parametrized by rational functions iff its genus is zero. Your example has genus $2$, so it has no rational parametrization. For more details, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.6219) by Lemmermeyer or [this book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540737247) by Winkler, Sendra, and Perez-Diaz.

Comment: @Nosrati Thanks for finding that (I searched on Math.SE but didn't find that one). I've edited to emphasize what I think is not being asked there.

Comment: Don't worry about duplication. The people's vote is dominant :)

Comment: @Nosrati That question doesn't have 'the' answer. And there is one, or at least a better attempt at one which I will try to supply there.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know people choose duplication :(, do you want to reopen it? Did you see two references had given by @Quasicoherent?.

Comment: @nosrati ?? You were the first person to vote to close as a duplicate! But anyway, it's unfortunate that my eye's _did_ miss that question which is definitely a duplicate question (or the search box and question title editor lookahead is not the same search as that for 'Related Questions'). Anyway, no, no need to reopen. I'll redirect my efforts at the other question. I'm still surprised at how little attention that one got.

Comment: So sorry ...... was my fault.

Comment: @Nosrati I've reread the answers at the other question and links there. Also I've bee going through Cox-Little-O'Shea Ideals-Varieties-Algorithms (all about Groebner Bases), and it's as though the whole theory is dancing around parametrization (the intro seems to be have it as an application), yet there is never an outright statement of what is possible. It leads me to believe that what can be done is a simple consequence, just never stated outright as a theorem or lemma. I still think there is a better answer than at the other question but I can't articulate it myself.

Comment: @Mitch Perhaps what you want is just a simple argument, but on the other hand it may lead to an important topic or at least an important theorem. However, this requires a lot of study and a well-trained mathematician in the differential geometry (or other related) field who can easily decide for you.

Comment: @Mitch The first part of my previous comment---a curve has a rational parametrization iff it has genus zero---is almost tautological, since a parametrization is by definition a birational map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to C$. Most books stop there. It's quite a bit harder to explicitly compute a parametrization, even if you know a curve has genus zero. This is something I've been very interested in for a long time, but I still haven't found the perfect resource. The book by Winkler et al. is probably the most detailed, but not necessarily the best place to start. Here are a few others.

Comment: [An Introduction to Parametrizing Rational Curves](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/VictoriaWood.pdf) by Victoria Wood (an REU paper); [Algorithm for the Parameterization of Rational Curves Revisited](http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jgg/jgg15/j15h1bizz.pdf) by Bizzarri and Lavicka; [Rational Parametrizations of Algebraic Curves using a Canonical Divisor](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771719690084X) by van Hoeij. Bizzarri's bachelor thesis was the most friendly resource I've found on this topic, but I can no longer find it online, unfortunately.

Comment: Finally, if you want to try to get your question reopened, I'd recommend making a request in [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today). You could also make a request in [the CRUDE chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude). (CRUDE stands for Close/Reopen/Undelete/Delete/Edit.)

Comment: @Quasicoherent Excellent comments. It's a much better start than otherwise. Can you moosh your first two comments together into an answer on the linked open question. I put a 50 put bounty on it.

Comment: I think the duplicate question is actually quite a bit broader than yours, now that you've specified that you're looking for a parametrization by rational functions. (I'm not sure the OP there was thinking about polynomial or rational functions.) However, I think your question might actually be a duplicate of [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329/parametrizing-implicit-algebraic-curves).