# Geometry vs Topology

Tags: geometric-topology, noncommutative-geometry

I am a beginner in functional analysis and operator algebras. Recently I stumbled upon the two subjects, non-commutative topology and non-commutative geometry.

What are the similarities and differences between them?

Comment: Never heard of noncommutative topology.

Comment: In a broader sense, [this has already been answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/geometry-and-topology#:~:text=Algebraic%20geometry%20is%20about%20the,no%20singularities%2C%20i.e.%20homogeneous%20objects.)